I want to get the current price at the time the script is launched and save it in a variable
This is my first time writing an indicator, I want to make it like stoploss, so that when the price goes up, the indicator (the line below) goes up along with the price, and when the price goes down, the indicator (the line below) stays in place, expecting that the price might touch the line.
But here's the problem: my variable for storing the price at the time of launch completely coincides with the real-time price and is constantly updated. Is it even possible to eat something like this?
I'll be very glad if you light it up, how to do it correctly :)
currentPrice = close

var float lowerLevel = na 

if na(lowerLevel)
    lowerLevel := currentPrice * 0.97 

if currentPrice > lowerLevel * 1.03
    lowerLevel := currentPrice * 0.97 

lineLength = 300 
var line lowerLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.green, width=1)

line.set_xy1(lowerLine, bar_index - lineLength, lowerLevel)
line.set_xy2(lowerLine, bar_index + lineLength, lowerLevel)

label.new(bar_index, currentPrice, "Current Price: " + str.tostring(currentPrice), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white, textcolor=color.blue)
label.new(bar_index, lowerLevel, "Lower Level: " + str.tostring(lowerLevel), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white, textcolor=color.green)



It seems I found the answer to my question, at least it's broken, but it works, I checked it on a 1 minute time frame.
// Current price calculation
currentPrice = close

// Variable to store levels
var float lowerLevel = na // Initially uninitialized

// Flag to control updates
var bool isUpdating = true

// Initialize lowerLevel only on the first run
if na(lowerLevel)
    lowerLevel := currentPrice * 0.97 // Set the level to 3% below the current price on the first bar

// Check to update lowerLevel
if currentPrice > lowerLevel * 1.03
    lowerLevel := currentPrice * 0.97 // Update lowerLevel to 3% below the current price only if price has increased more than 3%
    isUpdating := true  // Allow further updates

// Stop updating if the price drops
if currentPrice < lowerLevel
    isUpdating := false // Block updates

// Check for price touching the lowerLevel
if low <= lowerLevel and high >= lowerLevel
    label.new(bar_index, lowerLevel, "Success! Price touched the green line.", style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white, textcolor=color.green)

// Set lines
lineLength = 300 // line length
var line lowerLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.green, width=1)

// Update the line only when the price rises and updates are allowed
if isUpdating
    line.set_xy1(lowerLine, bar_index - lineLength, lowerLevel)
    line.set_xy2(lowerLine, bar_index + lineLength, lowerLevel)

// Debug logs
label.new(bar_index, currentPrice, "Current Price: " + str.tostring(currentPrice), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white, textcolor=color.blue)
label.new(bar_index, lowerLevel, "Lower Level: " + str.tostring(lowerLevel), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white, textcolor=color.green)


“…at least it's broken, but it works”—What does this mean?
